# How to get near value from range in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to find nearest value from mysql database table of give value, what i want to do is:

**CASE1:** if i am giving input 2500 to pincode then i am retrieving record corresponding to that pincode value from database.

**CASE2:** if record not exits for entered pincode(2500) , i have to get nearest value of 2500 and its corresponding records too.

Stored procedure i am currently calling for **CASE1** sp_findlocation('XXXXXXXX','2500',@addresss)

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_findlocation`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_findlocation`(IN mobile VARCHAR(20),IN pincode VARCHAR(20),OUT address VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN   
    IF(pincode IS NOT NULL AND pincode!= '') THEN
        SET @c1 = '';
        SET @c2 = '';
        SET @c3 = '';
        SET @qry='select locality,store_name,contact_number INTO @c1,@c2,@c3 from test_upload where pin=? limit 1';
        PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
        SET @c = pincode;
        EXECUTE stmt USING @c;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        IF(@c1!='' || @c2!=''||@c3!='') THEN    
            SET address= CONCAT(@c1, '|',@c2,'|',@c3);      
        ELSE
            SET address= "No Result";
        END IF; 
    ELSE    
        SET address="Please enter valid pin code";
    END IF; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

what i will do for geting records including **CASE2**?

Comment: To get nearest value I would go with `ORDER BY ABS(pin-?) LIMIT 1`

Comment: Thank you @dev-null-dweller for quick reply, what if i have to return only that nearest found pincode?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, `LIMIT 1` is for making sure only one is returned?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller , no i am saying , what if i want to return found nearest pincode not its records

Comment: Make a new SELECT statement that selects only pincode?